# How do you scale two div elements together inside another div with min-height?

Tags: html, css

This question is very close to a number of other ones out there but I haven't been able to find the exact answer.  I am trying to teach myself CSS and make a simple blog page.

What I have so far is 5 div elements header, wrapper, main content, sidebar and  footer.  I am trying to position the header on top with the footer on the bottom the wrapper in between.  In the wrapper I want to have the main content and side bar.  Both the sidebar and main content need to scale height with the wrapper div.  The wrapper div has a min-height of 70%.  The issue is that I can get almost all of this to work accept for the inner div scaling part.  No matter what I try I can't get the sidebar to scale with the content.  I have tried everything I could find online and no success. The code is as follows:

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper { 
    min-height: 70%;
    width:100%;
}

#sidebar {
    width:200px;
    float: right;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
}

#content { 
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
}

#header { 
    height:100px; 
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
}

#footer {   
    height:100px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
}
```

and the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link href="./css/style.css?v=<?=time();?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        header
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar">
            sidebar
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            content
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        footer
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As I stated I am learning this so please go easy.  This is my first try at CSS.

I have the code live at http://thediycookbook.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#wrapper { 
    min-height: 70%;
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
}

#sidebar {
    width:200px;
    float: left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
    width:19%;
}

#content { 
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
    float:left;
    width:80%
}
```

Comment: This did the trick.  Is there a way to do this with the sidebar on the right?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link href="./css/style.css?v=<?=time();?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        header
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        
        <div id="content">
            content
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
<div id="sidebar">
            sidebar
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        footer
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: flex`to `#wrapper` to match the heights of its children, and add `width: calc(100% - 200px);` to `#content` to extend its width to the right border.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONYKdg